# Remove Delete Button for Wrong User?

Tags: php

I currently have a guestbook style thing that users post comments. Their username is stored in a cookie when logged on, and when a post is submitted their username is stored alongside their post in a mySQL database. I'm trying to remove the delete button next to the comment if the user logged in is not the one that posted it. Here is the nonworking code:

```
        <?php
        $username = $_COOKIE['sqlusername'];
        mysqlLogin();

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts`");
        $sqlCnt = mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if($sqlCnt != 0) {
            echo "<table align='center'><tr><td class='tdno'><u><H4>Message</H4></u></td><td class='tdno'><u><H4>Poster</H4></u></td><td class='tdno'><u><H4>Time</H4></u></td></tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                if($row['username'] != $username) {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                    echo "document.getElementById('delete').innerHTML = \"\";";
                    echo "</script>";
                }
                $id = $row['id'];
                echo "<form action='delete.php' method='POST'>";
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row['message'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['poster'];
                echo "</td><td align='center' width='10'>";
                echo $row['date'];
                echo "<td align='left' width='1'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>";
                echo "<span id='delete'><input type='submit' class='submit' value='Delete'></span>";
                echo "</td></tr>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "<div align='center'>Sorry, no posts found!</div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you dont add the form if user is not logged in as looking at the source would show a form for each entry advertising `delete.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
          if ($username == $row['poster']) {
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>";
            echo "<span id='delete'><input type='submit' class='submit' value='Delete'></span>";
          } else {
            echo " "
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe its the issue with your browser and javascript. Try this :

```
if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        if{ // IE 4
            document.all.id.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

else your logic looks fine(assuming you are storing the username and posts properly in database.)

Comment: Special cases for Netscape 4? This is 2011 we're living in, not 1998. There's no need for that.